# MacBook Pro with Intel graphics sends no signal to external monitor only in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro, external-display, intel-graphics

These is the low end MacBook Pro with Intel graphics. All the drivers are up to date. The display works fine with other computers, and even with this computer in OS X. The Intel graphics control panel shows that the monitor is connected, and I can change its resolution, but I still get no signal on the monitor. Any ideas?

Edit for clarity:

Both the Windows display control panel, and the Intel graphics control panel show that the display is connected. I have tried them to extended or mirroring, and neither one is sending signal to the external monitor. Again, it works in OS X, and with other computers, so the problem isn't in the monitor or the cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this specific type of conversion is not supported by the Intel Graphics controller I'll have to find a monitor with display port, or try a hdmi converter.

> Diego: Unfortunately you are trying to convert a digital signal to
>   analog one which is not supported by the video controller
>
> Diego: Display port can be only used for a TV with Display port or
>   converted to HDMI

Answer (score 0):

Is Windows set to display anything on the external screen? To check right click on the desktop and choose "*Screen Resolution*," next to "Multiple displays:" choose either "*Extend these displays*" or "*Duplicate these displays*"

[image: Windows 7 Screen Resolution]

Or press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> untill you can see the setup you want.

[image]

Also, make sure the resolution you have set for the external monitor is supported by it, this is especially true if it is a TV as they can be VERY picky about what they display.

Comment: Tried this. I've used the monitor on an older MacBook pro and used the windows-p key combination. No luck. The computer definitely believes that the monitor is attached, but the monitor is not detecting any signal.